# SQL Server : using SQL Proxy application\instance to indirectly query a database

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I am using Microsoft SQL Server (2008-2012)

I would like to avoid directly querying the database, and instead, use some kind of a proxy (ODBC-Like) which I will query via my application, and it will query the actual database, and return me the results.

The idea is to manually encrypt some columns and have a barrier which will make encryption / decryption transparent to the application connecting the database.

Is there an off the shelf solution for this? Or do I actually need to write my own custom odbc driver?

Comment: What solutions have you tried? Have you looked into the possibility of using symmetric keys, asymmetric keys, Transparent Data Encryption? When you say "querying the database," do you mean "querying tables?" If so, what about querying the data from views?

Comment: Using views, as in, creating a SP to which I pass the key as a parameter and it will retrieve a view with which I can work transparently, yes it's great but this means I have to go through every place in my application and change the query command - this may mean thousands of places which is exactly what i'm trying to avoid

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to encrypt your data? If you're trying to protect data at rest, then take a look at Transparent Data Encryption. Otherwise, I'd suggest a view with calls to something like `decryptbykey()` baked into it. You can open the key elsewhere (i.e. after connection open) so the selects can be "transparent" with respect to that part of your application.

Comment: @BenThul Yes i also considered this, as the SELECT may work (with one-line change to the app code), this still forces me to change my application, inorder to have every INSERT command contain the encryption function (ENCRYPTBYKEY())
I still think some kind of middle-man software is crucial in this situation.

Comment: You can put `instead of` triggers on views, so you can implement the encryption piece there.